# WinRM(WsMan) and NTLM authentication

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm, winrm, wsman

I'm trying to use NTLM authentication during WsMan connection. But the problem that WinRm doesn't support NTLM scheme directly.
Here is response headers:

```
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 401 [\r][\n]"
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0[\r][\n]"
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate[\r][\n]"
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "WWW-Authenticate: Kerberos[\r][\n]"
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "WWW-Authenticate: CredSSP[\r][\n]"
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 18:57:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
21:57:33.557 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
```

NTLM scheme is not mentioned in official documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.WsMan.Management/Get-WSManInstance?view=powershell-5.1

But it says

> Negotiate. Negotiate is a challenge-response scheme that negotiates
>   with the server or proxy to determine the scheme to use for
>   authentication. For example, this parameter value allows for
>   negotiation to determine whether the Kerberos protocol or NTLM is
>   used.

I'm trying to use SPNEGO schema

```
RegistryBuilder<AuthSchemeProvider> builder = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create().register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory());
```

But at the end, it fails https://pastebin.com/gGNEHGpx
So it looks like NTLM is sub-mechanism of SPNEGO, but how to use it correctly with Apache http-client?

Answer (score 1):

Negotiate implies Kerberos or NTLM. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tristank/2006/08/02/two-easy-ways-to-pick-kerberos-from-ntlm-in-an-http-capture/

Answer (score 0):

I found a SpNegoNTLMSchemeFactory that works correctly with WinRm
https://gist.github.com/moberwasserlechner/4690931

JCIFSEngine.java == apache NTLMEngineImpl.java
SpNegoNTLMSchemeFactory.java == apache NTLMSchemeFactory.java

SpNegoNTLMScheme.java != apache NTLMScheme.java
But the only difference here is

```
  @Override
  public String getSchemeName() {
    return AuthSchemes.SPNEGO; //<- apache class return NTLM here
  }


  @Override
  public Header authenticate(final Credentials credentials, final HttpRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {
    ...
    buffer.append(": ");
    buffer.append(getSchemeName().toUpperCase());  //<- apache class return NTLM here
    buffer.append(" ");
    buffer.append(response);
    return new BufferedHeader(buffer);
  }
```